# How can I load a jpeg image from a buffer?

Tags: delphi, resources, jpeg, delphi-10.3-rio

I want to store a jpeg image in a RC_DATA resource, but not a single image in one single RC_DATA. There are many things in that RC_DATA, all muxed together. At runtime I load that RC_DATA in a bufer and extract all the object, including this Jpeg. Now I have this image in a memory buffer and I need to load it in a TJpegImage or TBitmap. How can I do that ? I saw that those classes doesn't have some methods to achieve this...

Comment: Seems like a perfect job for [`TJPEGImage.LoadFromStream`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.TJPEGImage.LoadFromStream).

Comment: I highly doubt you [multiplexed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplexing#Video_processing) data streams. Most likely you just [concatenated](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/concatenate) them. Your [bu**ff**ers](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/buffer#Noun_2).

Comment: Give each image a different id

Comment: @DavidHeffernan indeed, it will be simple that way but I don't want anyone to use a resource editor and extract that image.

Comment: @MarusNebunu: They can still use a resource editor to extract your images.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Yes, but it's combined with other things and ecrypted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the JPEG bytes from your buffer into a `TMemoryStream` (or, use a `TCustomMemoryStream` to point directly at the JPEG bytes to avoid making a copy). And then you can pass that stream to `TJPEGImage.LoadFromStream()`.

Comment: But if I use `TCustomMemoryStream` I must make e new class from it and override `SetPointer` procedure ? Because I see that it si protected and I cannot access it as it is... Hm, it seems it cannot be ovrride it because is not a virtual procedure.

Comment: @MarcusNebunu No, `SetPointer()` is not virtual, so you can't override it. You would create a new class that *calls* `SetPointer()`, such as in the constructor, eg: `type TMemBufferStream = class(TCustomMemoryStream) public constructor Create(ABuffer: Pointer; ASize: NativeInt); end; ... constructor TMemBufferStream.Create(ABuffer: Pointer; ASize: NativeInt); begin inherited SetPointer(ABuffer, ASize); end;`